# XML Modify attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am working on XML structures and cannot solve a problem;

```
SET @V_XML.modify('replace value of (/Table/Header/Column/@readonly)[1] with "False" ')
```

This is working but '[1]' is my column number and i want to make it parametric.

```
SET @V_XML.modify('replace value of (/Table/Header/Column/@readonly)[sql:variable("@MYCOLUMNNUM")] with "False" ')
```

this fails me

please help, thank you

Comment: Please share you XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share your XML, so I devised it on my own.

If you need to change an attribute value in a particular column by its sequential number, you need to use a predicate right after the **Column** element.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @V_XML XML = 
(N'<Table>
    <Header>
        <Column readonly="True"></Column>
        <Column readonly="True"></Column>
        <Column readonly="True"></Column>
    </Header>
</Table>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @MYCOLUMNNUM INT = 3;

-- before
SELECT @V_XML;

SET @V_XML.modify('replace value of (/Table/Header/Column[sql:variable("@MYCOLUMNNUM")]/@readonly)[1] with "False"');

-- after
SELECT @V_XML;
```